# How to connect SAS cable to P440 Cable

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid

We just bought a brand new HP Smart Array P440, we placed it in the PCI and the server did detect the RAID controller.

I want to connect the disks to the raid controller but the slot on the Smart Array is different than most RAID controllers have.

My cable looks like this:

[image]

This is how the Array controller slot looks like:

[image]

Comment: Which cable do I need to use?

Comment: What type of server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

We're missing a lot of information here.

- Where did you buy the RAID controller from?
- What type of server are you using it with?

You need a cable with a special connector on one end. It's called an "Internal x8 Mini-SAS double-wide connector". But the other end of the cable depends on how you'll be using the controller and what model sever you're installing in.

HP have a [special website](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-4154ENW&cc=us&lc=en) detailing the cable and controller combinations for situations like this.

http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-4154ENW&cc=us&lc=en